# Java + MongoDB задать путь хранения БД

Tags: java, база-данных, mongodb

Я разрабатываю приложение (на джаве) которое работает с файлами на внешнем жестком диске. Также есть база данных монго. Я хочу, чтобы БД находилась на внешнем жестком диске (там же, где и файлы) и программа могла работать с ней на "любом" компьютере к которому подключили данный диск.

Подскажите, пожалуйста, как можно указывать путь к файлам БД при подключении к ней?

сейчас подключаюсь к БД так:

```
mongoClient = new MongoClient(new MongoClientURI("mongodb://localhost:27017"));
database = mongoClient.getDatabase("baseName");
```

но в этом случае монго самостоятельно определяет место хранения БД.

Comment: Обычно такие вещи - это настройка самой СУБД, вот тут есть ответ как менять кофиг или задать свой собственный http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12738322/what-is-the-default-database-path-for-mongodb

Comment: спасибо, но как я понимаю, в этом случае все БД перенесуться на новое расположение и на каждом компьютере нужно перенастраивать конфиг((

Comment: Верно. Заранее вы же не можете знать, к примеру, как смонтируется носитель в систему(к примеру каким диском) - а это уже другой путь. Если хотите переносную БД - посмотрите в сторону embedded БД